# else = invalid syntax.. What to change?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

```py
if random_numbers == predicted_numbers: seed_found=True # body of if statement
predicted_seed=seed 
else: 
attempts += 1
```

error says
"Cell In[48], line 16
else:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I want the error "invalid syntax" for 'else' to go away

[I still made a mistake][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRCi5.png

Comment: The indention of your first and second line is incorrect: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Comment: You mean like "else attempts += 1: " and underneath "print"?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else

Comment: I saw it and changed it but the error won't go away. I still do something wrong.

Comment: as @Rbn14_gtf pointed out, correct the indentation error for the code to work

Comment: Oh I meant that I still made a mistake. Not someone else. I believe it is the truth what's being told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the identation of your code is the problem
Try this:

```
if random_numbers == predicted_numbers: 
  seed_found=True # body of if statement
  predicted_seed=seed 
else: 
  attempts += 1
```

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Thank you for being so patient and taking the time! It fixed it!

Comment: Please use an indentation of 4 spaces per level, as strongly recommended by the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).